# Deploy Web App from Visual Studio Code to Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I have a "Hello, World" Node.js app. My app has the following structure:

```
/
  /src
    index.html
  package.json
  README.md
```

The `index.html` file just contains this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am successfully running this locally using `npm test` via `lite-server`. My `package.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "name":"my-hello-world",
  "version":"0.0.1",
  "description":"This is a test",
  "main":"index.js"
  "scripts": {
    "start": "lite-server --baseDir=src"
  },
  "author":"",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server":"^2.5.3"
  }
}
```

I am attempting to deploy this via the "[Azure App Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azureappservice)" Visual Studio Code extension. To do this, I:

1. Right-click on my app service in the explorer.
2. Choose "Deploy to Web App..."
3. Select the "src" directory.
4. Click the "Deploy" button

When I click "Browse Website", I just see a "Hey, Node developers!" splash screen. However, when I run `npm start` on my local machine, the "Hello World!" page shows as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy the node web to azure and configure the `bs-config.json`, the page will show error page. Then I check the Application Logs, then I found it will open localhost port and I check the [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server#lite-server) github page, found it uses [BrowserSync](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync), it's a **tool for local development**.

[image]

If you just want to test node web with azure, you could try with the code provided by the official doc: [Create a Node.js web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs). You don't need change anything just extract the zip file and deploy it. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy sample application of node https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs. I followed the step from the documentation and got the Hello World on screen.
For more details Please refer to https://blog.darrenjrobinson.com/how-to-build-and-deploy-an-azure-nodejs-webapp-using-visual-studio-code/